# Scriptable image manipulation

Tags: image-processing, shader, pixel-shader

I'm desperately in need of some software. What I'm looking for is some type of image editor that has support for pixel level manipulation by means of some type of scripting language (think HLSL/GLSL pixel shaders.)

Requirements:

- Access to pixel data from script.
- Support for 32-bit floating point images with alpha
- Can read and write multiple file formats (TIFF, PNG, BMP...)

Does something like this already exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adobe's PixelBender has some of this. So does Chrome. You didn't really specify a context, but... as an image editor, look into Pixel Bender.

Comment: Looks interesting. It may be about the closest thing there is.